# Mocking Axios Reject Rest Call

Tags: javascript, angular, axios, promise

I have a utility class:

utils.ts

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.responseType = 'json';

export class UserUtils {

    public updateUserData(data) {
        return axios.post('http://mock.rest.server.com:1234/rest/update/user/', data, 
            {
                withCredentials: true,
                responseType: 'json' as 'json
            })
            .then(resp => {
                return resp;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return throwError('error updating user data');
            });
    }

}
```

And my component classes call the above as per:

userComponent.ts

```
export class UserComponent {
    import { UserUtils } from './utils';
    

    public userUtils: UserUtils = new UserUtils();


    // Btn click method
    public update(content) {
        this.userUtils.updateUserData(content) // <-- call made here
           .then((data) => {

               this.showSuccessModal(); // <- trying to test this

           }, (err) => {

               this.showErrorModal(error); // <- trying to test this

           });
    }

}
```

I am trying to test the positive (showSuccessModal) / negative (showErrorModal) scenarios on userComponent.ts

userComponent.spec.ts

```
import { UserComponent } from '../../../user/userComponent';
import { UserUtils } from '../../../user/utils';


 describe('User Comp test', () => {

     beforeAll(done => (async () => {

         Testbed.configureTestingModule({
             declarations: [
                 UserComponent
             ]
         });
         await TestBed.compileComponents();
     })().then(done).catch(done.fail);

     describe('User Comp (with beforeEach)', () => {
         let component: UserComponent;
         let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserComponent>;

         beforeEach(() => {                 
             fixture = await TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
             component = fixture.componentInstance;
         });

         it('should show error modal', () => {
             let errorModal = spyOn(component, 'showErrorModal');
             spyOn(component.userUtils, 'updateUserData').and.returnValue(Promise.reject('error updating'));

             component.update({test: 'test');
             expect(errorModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
         });
     });
 }
```

However when running tests, i see:

```
Error: Expected spy showErrorModal to have been called
    at <Jasmine>
```

It looks like in the test, the 'successful' route it always called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the solution - its to callFake and then reject the Promise:

```
import { UserComponent } from '../../../user/userComponent';
import { UserUtils } from '../../../user/utils';


 describe('User Comp test', () => {

     beforeAll(done => (async () => {

         Testbed.configureTestingModule({
             declarations: [
                 UserComponent
             ]
         });
         await TestBed.compileComponents();
     })().then(done).catch(done.fail);

     describe('User Comp (with beforeEach)', () => {
         let component: UserComponent;
         let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserComponent>;

         beforeEach(() => {                 
             fixture = await TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
             component = fixture.componentInstance;
         });

         it('should show error modal', () => {
             let errorModal = spyOn(component, 'showErrorModal');
             let spyPromise = spyOn(component.userUtils, 'updateUserData').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({status: 200....}));

             component.update({test: 'test');
             expect(errorModal).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

             errorModal.mockClear();
             spyPromise.mockClear();
             spyPromise.and.callFake(() => Promise.reject());

             component.update({test: 'test');
             expect(errorModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
         });
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
.catch(error => {
    return throwError('error updating user data');
});
```

resolve is Observable, You try:

```
.catch(error => {
    throw 'error updating user data';
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Should that matter given i am spying on the utils call? ie: spyOn(component.userUtils, 'updateUserData').and.returnValue(Promise.reject('error updating'));